# When is the pushforward of a sheaf isomorphic to the pullback along a section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $p:X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module on $X$. Suppose $s:S\to X$ is a section of $p$. Then when do we have an isomorphism $s^{\ast}\mathcal{F}\cong p_{\ast}\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: I don't know about a general criterion but this will not happen often. Eg if $S$ is the spectrum of a field and $\cal F$ is a line bundle, the rank of the left-hand side is one but the the rank of the right-hand side can be arbitrary (consider ${\cal O}(n)$ on projective space).

Comment: There is a natural surjective morphism $F \to s_*s^*F$, let $F'$ be its kernel. Then there is an exact sequence $$0 \to F' \to F \to s_*s^*F \to 0$$ and pushing it forward along $p$, one obtains $$0 \to p_*F' \to p_*F \to s^*F \to R^1p_*F' \to R^1p_*F \to 0.$$ So, $$p_*F' = R^1p_*F' = 0$$ is a sufficient condition for $p_*F = s^*F$.